USB devices assign error and usb descriptor error
Microsoft has an example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbinterface?view=winrt-19041
When I try to implement this I receive the following errors,
Use of unassigned local variable 'device'   at line
     foreach (var interf in device.Configuration.UsbInterfaces)

and,
Argument 2: cannot convert from null to out Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbInterfaceDescriptor, at line
if (descriptors.Count >= 2 &&
UsbInterfaceDescriptor.TryParse(descriptors[0], null) ==
                            true &&
                            descriptors[1].Length == 0x0D &&
                            descriptors[1].DescriptorType == 0x24)

Thanks in advance for the help.

It's not a ready to use example. After a few lines, it already says: "Get the UsbDevice object. Not shown."

Thanks for the help. Actually thee was many errors and I fixe all accept the last two.
